# Error with both blogdown:new_site() and New Project > website using blogdown

Tags: blogdown

I am following ["blogdown: Creating Websites with R Markdown"](https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/) and unfortunately am stuck in Section 1.2. I created a new project in an empty folder, but get this error:

> blogdown::new_site()
> 'C:\Users\rose89\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site ".' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
> Error in shell(cmd, mustWork = TRUE, intern = intern) :
> '"C:\Users\rose89\AppData\Roaming\Hugo\hugo.exe" new site "." --force -f toml' execution failed with error code 1

I have tried removing and re-installing blogdown. When I try File > New Project > New Directory > website using blogdown, I get a popup error: [R code execution error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7wIN.png)

I am using Windows, R studio 1.3.959 and R version 4.0.2. Here is some other info:

> getwd()
> [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O7wIN.png) "C:/Users/rose89/Documents/anothernewproject"

> list.files('content', '.md$', full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE)
> character(0)

I prefer to use the first approach in the console, but feel hopeless as I can't even get the "point and click" approach to work. If anyone has suggestions, I would greatly appreciate them! Thank you. Also this is my first post on StackOverflow and first time trying Blogdown, apologies if my question is not phrased clearly!

Update: I believe the error is due to my domain's "group policy" blocking hugo.exe (and other zipped .exe programs) on my Windows machine. I am working with my department's IT department to find a work-around.